# iphone sqlite insert... EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, sqlite, insert, exc-bad-access

First of all, I'm fairly new to iPhone development, and brand new to incorporating sqlite3 in my app. I have used it in my Android and Blackberry apps, so I know basic commands and such. Here is my problem: I created a db and table programmatically (both were created correctly). Here is the code I used to creative the table:

```
const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EXPENSES (id integer primary key autoincrement, unix_date integer, date_time text, purpose text, start_mile text, end_mile text, distance text, fees text, party_id integer)";
```

The table was created properly.

This the function I used to save data:

```
- (void) saveData
{
sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
NSString *timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (long)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &expenseDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO EXPENSES (timestamp, date_time, purpose, start_mile, end_mile, distance, fees, party_id) VALUES (\"%d\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%d\")", 9, @"date", @"purpose", @"start", @"end", @"miles", @"tolls", 0];
    const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(expenseDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
     //   status.text = @"Contact added";

    } else {
      //  status.text = @"Failed to add contact";
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(expenseDB);
}
[timestamp release];
```

}

When I run this code, I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS from the main thread. I thought this error generally showed up when an NSString value was assigned as string value?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't release timestamp, you're not allocating or retaining it.

```
[timestamp release];
```

Comment: Ah! That was it. Still in the process of mastering memory management...been skating by with Java. Thanks!